# Java. Balls split after collision and move in different directions

Tags: java, collision, intersection

I have a program where i create balls that bounce around. When two balls collide, both should split into two smaller balls, start moving in different directions.

This is how I handle collision

```
public boolean intersects (Ball b) {
        double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((this.x - b.x), 2) + Math.pow((this.y - b.y), 2));
        if (this.size / 2 + b.size / 2  >= distance && !(this.equals(b))) {
            return  true;
        } else return false;
```

I am looking for an idea, that will help to decide where to place smaller balls, so that they don't immediately collide again.  I have tried different maneuvers but they all end up too close to each other so they all start splitting a bouncing and it become a chaos.

Here is the class Ball

```
public Ball(double x, double y, double size, double dx, double dy) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;
```

To move the balls I do the following

```
b.x = b.x + b.dx;
b.y = b.y + b.dy;
```

For the moment when the balls collide, i have two Ball Objects. I know the coordinates of their centers: `x`, `y` ,  speed `dx` with which they move along the x-axis and speed `dy` along the y-axis

I leave out the code that handles the view, cause I basically need a solution, how to change `dx`, `dy`, `x` and `y` for 4 balls, so that all of them move away from each other and do not immediately collide.

I don't really need code-solution , but rather a general idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have two problems.  The first is that your four "new" balls are all starting at or near the point of collision, and your collision detector might immediately perceive them as colliding.  To solve this, you could mark the "new" balls as unable to collide with each other for a pulse or two of your collision detector.  I'd need to see the code to give a better solution.

Secondly, you'll probably want to randomize the result vector of the four "new" balls.  Just set dx and dy randomly for each and that should be good enough.

Comment: your second suggestion actually gives me an idea.

if I get the point (coordinates) of intersection, i could place 4 balls around that point and set their dx and dy basing on that.

because for now I change dx according to the previous direction of the current ball, but it doesn't take in account the position of the other one.